# Can I push a CloudPage multi-checkbox to a single data extension text field?

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

I am trying to create a CloudPage to collect customer preferences into a data extension, which we would then feed back into our Sales Cloud using the connector.

I would like to have a multi-select checkbox for each different preference, e.g.:

Which animals do you like?
[] Horse
[] Dog
[] Cat

I can only see a way to do this if I assign each of these options to an individual field in a data extension, i.e. '[] Horse' to a 'Horse' field, '[] Dog' to a 'Dog' field, etc.

But the results need to feed back into a multi-picklist field in sales cloud, i.e. 'Horse; Cat' or 'Dog; Cat', so we need for customer selections to go into a single field that we can carry over.

Is it possible to have a check list in a CloudPage push to a single text attribute in a data extension? So if someone were to select [x] Horse, [x] Cat, the field would be: 'Horse;Dog;'?

Comment: Yes, just concatenate the results together before you save them to a DE field. I have this article about multi-select picklists in Salesforce but the logic would be the same: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2020/10/05/working-with-salesforce-multi-select-picklists-in-ampscript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @zuzannamj has said, I concatenated the results and was able to push the field the SFSC (I ended up using SQL in Automation Studio rather than AMPScript as my knowledge of AMPScript is limited.